# Exclude files and folders from bundling in reactjs npm run build

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using `reactJS` I have two separate subdomains `app1` and `app2` both used shared components. So I just want to **exclude** app2 views in app1 bundle to reduce size and in app2 **exclude** app1 views.

**Folder Structure**

```
reactJs/
├─ index.js
├─ app.js
├─ src/
│  ├─ common/
│  ├─ store/
│  ├─ utils/
│  ├─ api/
│  ├─ hooks/
│  ├─ views/
│  │  ├─ app1/
│  │  ├─ app2/
│  ├─ layouts/
```

I want something like this

**package.json**

```
{
  "build-app1": "react-scripts build --exclude=./src/views/app2"
  "build-app2": "react-scripts build --exclude=./src/views/app1"
}
```

Comment: But if your `app2` never `imports` an `app1` module won't it automatically be excluded?

Comment: yes `app2` never imports `app1` views but main file and `routes.js` file contain both views from `app1` and `app2`